# Firefox 3.6 for Mac font problem (picks wrong font)

Tags: css, fonts, firefox3.6

I have the following problem with Firefox 3.6 on Mac. Windows and older versions of FF work perfect.

The body is defined like this:

```
body {color:#000;font:normal 12px/16px "Cambria", Times, Times New Roman, Georgia, serif;background:#fff}
```

But my h1, h2 and some other tags (sometimes a list item is in the right font, sometimes it isn't) are in Verdana (wrong should be Camrbia) font... I don't know why... The standard FF font is Times... My other texts are in the right Cambria font.

Even when I remove the stylesheet the same tags have the wrong font, they should be Times but they are Verdana -> Very strange no?

PS: I'm sorry but I can't post the whole stylesheet...

Answer (score 1):

You have to set font families on h1, h2, etc. tags too. Also you have to write font-families in quotes if the font name consists of more words:

```
h1 {font-family:Cambria, Times, "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif;}
```

I suggest you to install Firebug plugin for firefox and see which styles are being applied to your tags. Also check if there is not another stylesheet that is being loaded in the header.

Comment: I tryed this: h1 {font-size:30px;line-height:30px;font-weight:bold;margin:0 0 8px 0; font-family:Cambria, serif}
But it still doesn't work...

Comment: If you can post a link to a live example of your site - it's hard to tell the problem if you don't see all code.